# How to handle a question that copies another one, yet is not a dupe

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

As from query title, I have found a question that is almost a word-by-word copy of another question, yet is not marked as a dupe.

- [2010: Custom List Template ID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/2010-custom-list-template-id) - asked Jan 29 '14 at 10:03
- [How to get custom list template id?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/147633/how-to-get-custom-list-template-id) -asked Jun 29 '15 at 12:27

Now, I am not really sure that the most recent one is a dupe or not. The small changes seem to indicate that they may cover different approaches (client side opposed to server side object mode).

**Let's for the sake of this question assume this isn't a case of dupe question**

What I am asking here is if it is allowed to "copycat" the **text** of another question to this extreme, even if the changed parts are sufficient to create a different question? How should we handle a case like this? It is reasonable to call for plagiarism... on a question?

I am asking because I don't really know if a question (let's for a second forget about possible included code samples - that would be different) as simple as this one could be "plagiarized" - and I wouldn't also really punish to hardly an user that may just be trying to use the original text as a starting point to build a decent question (maybe one could be able to  read English well enough to understand the question, but be at lost writing one from scratch?).

Can anyone provide some feedback about how to go from here? And... there are some implication that should be considered in regards to Stack Exchange content licensing?

Comment: The issue is likely one more of "lack of appropriate attribution so as to comply with the CC BY-SA license" as that is what the original question is licensed under.  It is, however, poor form and makes it harder to find the *right* question as both contain the same text.

Answer (score 4):

Don't close either. I'd recommend you edit them to include a link in a blurb that goes something like, "my question is similar to this other one (add link here), but is about (differences) instead." That would take care of any copycat or plagiarism concerns.

If they're similar questions, but not duplicates, then that means they're different questions which will garner different answers. And at the end of the day, they're both accomplishing what SE is here for, they're making this a place where you can get your questions answered.